# AngularJS changing controller parameter

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have been ploughing into AngularJS and am trying to get my head around how everything links together but I've become a bit stuck.

How can I pass a variable to change the JSON that is loaded and shown on the page?
I thought it would be a button click and the directive would talk to the controller, but how I'm not so sure.

If i have my JSON as something like this as in controller...

```
var id = 'peter'; 
var person = $resource('http://myjson.com/'+id+'.json')
```

I can't figure out how I would change the `id` based on button clicks for example.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to explain as simple as possible, you can pass data as argument to a function from HTML to controller using the [ngClick](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick) directive.
The function inside the controller will be invoked because it has a binding to the **ngClick** directive using the [$scope](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope).

**Example**:

html:

```
<div ng-app="App"  ng-controller="ctrl">
    <div ng-repeat="itemId in items">
        <button ng-click="myClickFunc(itemId)">click {{itemId}}</button>
    </div>

</div>
```

js:

```
var app=angular.module('App', ['ngResource']);

function ctrl($scope,$resource){
    $scope.items=[1,2,3,4];

    $scope.myClickFunc=function(itemId){

        var person = $resource('http://myjson.com/get/:id');
        person.get({id: itemId}).$promise.then(function(data) {
           // success
           $scope.myData = data;
        }, function(errResponse) {
           // fail
        });
    }
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/choroshin/zJ5G6/